# How to make all images fit/same size inside div & responsive

Tags: html, image, css

**Image:**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAGy0.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAGy0.jpg) 
All my images has a different size (width/height)  
I want to make all my images **fit & Responsive** inside div even the size of `width:100%+` i can use `overflow:hidden`to hide some parts, but I want to keep it all same `height` to make it **equal** and **still responsive!** like height is auto (`height:auto`)
I want to use this code `<div><img src=".."/></div>`
**I don't want to use/change code to style `background: url('..');`
or any `flex`  or any  `object-fit:...;` or use any javascript** 
**Image:**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltuef.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltuef.jpg)
 
**Image:**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VFFP.jpg)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VFFP.jpg)

```css
body,
html {
  background: #9b9;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

div {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/500"> Text(1)
</div>



<div>
  <img src="https://justifiedgrid.com/wp-content/gallery/life/biking/137646854.jpg"> Text(2)
</div>


<div>
  <img src="http://centraltibetanreliefcommittee.org/doh/photo-gallery/good-sliders/MenuCool5/images/image-slider-1.jpg"> Text(3)
</div>


<div>
 <img src="https://www.aussiespecialist.com/content/asp/en/sales-resources/image-and-video-galleries/_jcr_content/mainParsys/hero/image.adapt.1663.medium.jpg"> Text(4)
</div>
```

Comment: Your div and img both have height auto. Give div required height and add image height to 100%.

Comment: thanks, I just add `height:300px` to div (required) , I add `height:100%` to img.
But It show me something like this ( Code Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/packy/m2hof8nq/1/ , Image Sample: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VFFP.jpg ) I want to make my div responsive show like a right side of my image sample

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,
html {
  background: #9b9;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  object-fit:cover;
}

div {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/500"> Text(1)
</div>



<div>
  <img src="https://justifiedgrid.com/wp-content/gallery/life/biking/137646854.jpg"> Text(2)
</div>


<div>
  <img src="http://centraltibetanreliefcommittee.org/doh/photo-gallery/good-sliders/MenuCool5/images/image-slider-1.jpg"> Text(3)
</div>


<div>
 <img src="https://www.aussiespecialist.com/content/asp/en/sales-resources/image-and-video-galleries/_jcr_content/mainParsys/hero/image.adapt.1663.medium.jpg"> Text(4)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, Do you have another way if It doesn't use any  `object-fit:...`